# Android : Error SimpleDateFormat Unknown pattern character 'u'

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I use java 1.7.25
but found this error. what should I do?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'u'
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validateFormat(SimpleDateFormat.java:264)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validatePattern(SimpleDateFormat.java:319)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:365)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:249)
```

Here is my code

```
    public static int getDayNumberOfWeek(int day, String monthString, int yyyy) {
//http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
    int dayNumberOfWeek = 1;
    final String inputFormat = "MMM/dd/yyyy";
    final String outputFormat = "u";
    String dayString2Digit = DateTimeHelper.getTwoDigit(day);
    String inputTimeStamp = monthString + "/" + dayString2Digit + "/" + String.valueOf(yyyy);
    try {
        dayNumberOfWeek =Integer.valueOf(TimeStampConverter(inputFormat, inputTimeStamp,
                                                            outputFormat));
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dayNumberOfWeek;
}
```

Comment: which string are you trying to parse and which format did you use? Are you sure you're not using an old Java version?

Comment: u have any declaration u  in you program

Comment: Show us some code, please. Did you forget a backslash maybe?

Comment: There is no pattern character `u` (see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I use java 1.7.25

No, you don't - not if you're running on Android. You need to look at the Android documentation, not the Java 7 docs.

If you look at the [Android `SimpleDateFormat` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you'll see that `u` isn't listed there. I don't believe there's a format pattern character for "day of week as a number" in Android.

Were you really looking for that though? If you *just* want the day of the week as a number (without anything else) you can always use

```
String text = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
```

Comment: @um.anusorn: Because you're using Android, which doesn't run Java 1.7 - it's as simple as that.

Comment: The sad thing is that now the documentation includes the `u`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto API 24+ only.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using android, then you're not using Java 1.7.25. See the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html): there's no support for `u` in SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your problem is going to be in your `TimeStampConverter` class where you're passing in that "u" as the `outputFormat`.  "u" is not a valid format character in [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and you must be constructing a format string that contains it.

If you need to use the "u" as a literal, you'll need to enclose it in single quotes.