# Java SimpleDateFormat.format Throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, oracle, simpledateformat, illegalargumentexception

I need to get "Day number of week" from Date object. I tried to parse the Day number from the Date object as `new SimpleDateFormat("u").format(date)`.

According to the Oracle documentation of the [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) `u   : Day number of week (1 = Monday, ..., 7 = Sunday)`

This is the exception details

[image]

Comment: No `u` in android: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: SimpleDateFormat in Oracle java is different from SimpleDateFormat in java. Because there is no 'u' variable in Android SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Yeah true. Thanks RC.

Comment: it's look like same issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177268/android-error-simpledateformat-unknown-pattern-character-u

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the day of the date...

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(yourDate);//Replace your date with the date which u have
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); //create an instance of Calendar class
int Day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); //get current day of the week from the same instance
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain what it does and add some references to it.